# How can I say that if I want to return an operation on a list, but it stays the same when it comes out null?

Tags: python, function, nlp, map-function, isinstance

I have a list-of-list of word groups in Turkish. I want to apply stemming and I found turkishnlp package. Although it has some shortcomings, it often returns the right word. However, when I apply this to the list, I don't want the structure of my list to change and I want the words that he doesn't know to stay the same.

For example, I have this list:
**mylist = [['yolda','gelirken','kopek', 'gördüm'],['cok', 'tatlıydı']]**

And I wrote this function:

```
from trnlp import TrnlpWord
def tr_stemming(x):
    obj = TrnlpWord()
    obj.setword(x) if isinstance(x, str) else type(x)(map(tr_stemming, x))
    return obj.get_stem if isinstance(x, str) else type(x)(map(tr_stemming, x))
```

This function returns this list:

```
tr_stemming(mylist)
```

**[['yol', 'gelir', '', 'gör'], ['', 'tatlı']]**

However, I want to get this as the output:
**[['yol', 'gelir', 'kopek', 'gör'], ['cok', 'tatlı']]**

How can I update my function?
Thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could modify your function to:

```
def tr_stemming(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        obj = TrnlpWord()
        obj.setword(x)
        stem = obj.get_stem
        return stem if stem else x
    elif isinstance(x, list):
        return [tr_stemming(e) for e in x]
    
out = tr_stemming(mylist)
```

output:

```
[['yol', 'gelir', 'kopek', 'gör'], ['cok', 'tatlı']]
```